# Getting domain name and user id c#

Tags: c#

I want to get the domain name and username.

I want it to return domainname\username    forexample:    Cool\Beans

My application is linked to both an internett and a locally runned program.

When i run it locally(as an application) 
it returns The correct domainname and username. feks: Cool\Beans
That is when im using:

```
Environment.UserDomainName +"\\"+Environment.UserName
```

or when im using

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

When im trying to use this in the internett application it returns. Workgroup\Cool$

I have tried to use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` it returns null

Anyone have any ideas??

Thanks for answers

Comment: In your web site - it it configured to use integrated authentication?

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes my iis server is configured to use microsoft autentication.

Comment: "microsoft" authentication is not a "thing". Is it configured to use "Windows" authentication? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: Yes sorry, i meant windows autentication. Im thinking maybe it's the program/application that it's connected to thats making this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Environment.UserName/UserDomainName will return info for the executing user.
This will return the correct user info when running an application locally but in the case of a website running on IIS, this would get the info for the user used by IIS.

Take a look at this for windows authentication [Windows Authentication for ASP.NET MVC 4 - how it works, how to test it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224174/windows-authentication-for-net-mvc-4-how-it-works-how-to-test-it)