# Windows authentication keeps asking username password even credentials are correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication

I have developed an application to allow windows authentication and hosted it to the live server. in my local pc i am able to get the username password. but when i am accessing from web (e.g. websso.mydomain.com) it keeps asking credentials even after i entered correct credentials.

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

i have added above tags in web.config, hosting server is windows server 2008 R2. I have tried to get username from

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
Environment.Username
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

Is there any changes which needs to do in IIS or any steps to follow to configure windows authentication.

Installed IIS version is 7.5

Comment: Looks like you have a kerberos authentication problem...
What providers are active in the windows authentication properties in ISS? If you are fine with pure NTLM authentication, try to get rid of all other but the NTLM authentication provider of the windows authentication settings in IIS.
If you have to use kerberos, then you need to register some SPNs in case the app pool is running under a technical domain account.
Also ensure, that the users have at least read access on the web directory

Comment: I have used NTLM authentication, and have set at top of order. I wants to know is there any more configuration i need to do? or have to assign access to particular group?

Comment: try to remove all other providers than NTLM and then restart IIS. This could help.
Also try to grant Read&Execute to "Authenticated Users" on the directory of the web site.

Comment: I did the same as you suggested, i have now added a tag <allow user="domain\Domain Users"/> but still same response.

Comment: you should these users on the file system. in order to get it working, try to do the following changes in the web.config:<br/>
`<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue recently, try ensuring that the windows user has read access to the directory on the server.

Comment: i have given read and execute access to authenticated users.. isbthere any other group whpm i need to give access?

Comment: Is there any group like "Windows users" i did not found any thing like windows users.

Comment: @kbpanchal There is a group called `MACHINENAME\Users`, and if the machine is in a domain, there should be `DOMAINNAME\Domain Users` group. @DLeh thanks this solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

Checkk application pool owner in IIS

It should be network services

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you give more information on how someone could do this? To make your answer really useful for anyone that might be experiencing this same problem, if you edit your answer to give more detailed steps it would be better.

Answer (score 2):

websso.mydomain.com looks like internet domain name, not intranet domain name because it has sections. According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password you should use domain name without sections (e.g. http://websso/) or add your domain name to security settings of client browsers

Comment: **This worked for me, Thank you!** In my case i was using [NTLM authentication with Tomcat 8 along with Waffle](https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/master/Docs/tomcat/TomcatMixedSingleSignOnAndFormAuthenticatorValve.md).

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your `<authorization>` to include an `<allow>` element as I have done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22712582/939250).

E.g.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="yourdomain\someotheruser" />
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```