# Using Windows authentication by connecting it with userId, RoleId

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an mvc application that authenticates users by the DefaultConnection database. Now I want that user logged in with Windows pass could be automatically logged in, in my mvc app.

Can I do it with asp.net mvc?

Thank you for all suggestions that you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented here :- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs

> When you create a new ASP.NET MVC application, Windows authentication
>   is not enabled by default. Forms authentication is the default
>   authentication type enabled for MVC applications. You must enable
>   Windows authentication by modifying your MVC application’s web
>   configuration (web.config) file. Find the  section and
>   modify it to use Windows instead of Forms authentication like this:
>
> ```
> <authentication mode="Windows">
>
> </authentication>
> ```

For more information :- [Windows Authentication for ASP.NET MVC 4 - how it works, how to test it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224174/windows-authentication-for-net-mvc-4-how-it-works-how-to-test-it)

Comment: Thank you very much I think it will be very helpful!