# How to secure sections of a MVC application?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4

I have secured controller actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute to ensure only logged-in users can access parts of the site.  How do you secure resource directories, like ~/images?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Thanks... but I can't mark this as answer, as it's a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure the web.config file as explained in this question answer:

[How to lock down paths in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: someone voded your answer down.  It would be best that when people vote down they quantify it.  Voted up.