# mvc5 global authentication check

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, staging

I am trying to secure my staging site (mvc5 app) and am currently doing the following:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated){
            return View();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account"); 
    }
```

The above is far too laborious to be correct, I am certain that I shouldn't have to wrap all of my Views individually with an authentication check, however I can't seem to add a check in one location?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lock down paths in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: Sorry for possible duplicate - As someone who has looked for this (simple) answer, I didn't know to look for that question title.

Comment: No need to be sorry, it's extremely hard to ask a question about the details if you don't know the details.  All you can do is ask a question and hope someone understands what you meant.  Good luck! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [Authorize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) action filter:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account"); 
}
```

You can also use it on controller level to make sure all action methods require authentication:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //many action methods
}
```

If you want to use authentication for every action method in the application, you can add it as a global filter in FilterConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

If you do this, you have to use [AllowAnonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) filter on login actions so the user can authenticate themselves.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly the information on MVC authentication I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Authorize` attribute [`AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx):

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If the request is unauthenticated, MVC will redirect the user to the login route (defined in web.config authentication section).