# User authentication fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am developing `ASP.NET MVC 5` application and have problems with user authentication. All application

I have added to config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

to force user log in any way. But now I cannot `log in` and even `Register` button doesn't work. I am started from standard Visual Studio 2013 template, so I didn't make any customization.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lock down paths in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc).  MVC does not use the web.config for authorization, don't use it.

Comment: You say: _I have added to config_ and later: _I didn't make any customization_ ;P ASP.NET MVC 5 use ASP.NET Identity for authentication, so dont use Forms authentication.

Comment: I mean - any customization except .config.

Comment: What made you decide to just randomly change the web.config?  MVC5 doesn't use any of those entries, so why did you add them?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication was already implemented in the template. You have it implemented in `IdentityModels.cs` and `AccountController.cs` no need to add anything, Only if you wish to use OpenAuth.