# Forms Authentication not redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, form-authentication

I am trying to incorporate forms authentication into my web application. If I try to load any page without logging in it will not redirect the user to the login page but instead load the requested page. As an example if I try to load ~/Home/About without logging in it will proceed to load the page without redirecting me to ~/Account/Login. This is the first time I have tried to implement form authentication and I am struggling to see the problem.

I believe I have added the correct settings to the web.config file on the root. They are as follows.

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="chasAuth" loginUrl="~/Account/Login"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
 </system.web>
```

I have another web.config file that resides in the Views folder. I have also tried to add these setting to this file however this results in a different problem. I get the following error message:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file >required to service this request. Please review the specific error details >below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as >allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error >can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in >IIS.

I have tried to configure the virtual directory as an application in IIS as my research into the error has suggested however I can't seem to find the application in IIS. I am using localhost, or the ASP.NET Development Server, to debug my code. It is not up on a server yet. Would this be the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to lock down paths in ASP.NET MVC? - Absolutely do not use the web.config...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I have tried putting [Authorize] on the Home/About ActionResult but it still doesn't work

Comment: What specific version of MVC?