# App with windows auth asks for login

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I have auth set to Windows because it will be running on company intranet.  Web.config looks like:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I am building in VS 2013. Each day, the first time I run the app it pops up the auth required login box and once i give it my windows creds, it is fine (I assume it caches the creds).  I want the app to just start up with and not ask the valid user for login creds.

I thought this was the behavior of Windows Authentication.  Is there an IIS Express setting I need to change? Something else needed in the web config?

Comment: Regardless of which authentication scheme you decide to use (Forms, Identity, Windows), the Authoization tag is absolutely not the correct way to lock down an MVC application.  Please take a look at [How to lock down paths in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc/11765196#11765196).

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the web application domain as a "Local Intranet" site in Internet Explorer (Chrome will inherit this setting from IE, but I believe Firefox will have to be configured manually).  This can be accomplished through "Internet Options --> Security --> Local intranet --> Sites --> Advanced --> Add this website".

You will then need to configure automatic logon as outlined in this link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572939%28v=office.13%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396