# Invoke Forms Authentication for All Requests ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, iis-8, integrated-pipeline-mode

I am trying to ensure that any request, for any URL invokes the Forms Authentication module, and redirects to the login page.  This currently works for any controller with the authorize attribute, but doesn't work for things such as /Content/site.css or any other /[Page]

I followed the instructions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/28/iis7-making-forms-authentication-to-work-for-all-the-requests.aspx), without any success.

The summary is, that based on everything I've sough after online, I end up at needing to remove the "managedHandler" preCondition from the "FormsAuthentication" module entry under the "modules" element in the Web.config.  I remove it (and several other modules just for testing, to no avail).  Also I do not use the "Authorize" element in Web.config because that is not best practice for MVC application, so I am not looking into authorizing or not authorizing specific file paths.

```html
<modules> 
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />    
    <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" /> 
    <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />    
    <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />    
    <remove name="UrlAuthorization" />    
    <add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" />    
    <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />    
    <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" />    
</modules>
```

Any thoughts?

Thank You.

Comment: If FormsAuthenticationModule were to check every request for whether it is authenticated or not and to redirect if it is not, how is that different from writing a custom HttpModule and setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can register `Autorize` as global filter this way authentication and authorization will be required for all the actions in your application (use `AllowAnonymous` attribute on actions that you want to be available for non authorized users) :

```
public class FilterConfig
{

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, Container container)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());                  
    }
}
```

As far as I know, you don't need to modify anything in `modules` config for this issue

Now regarding the static content:

You can try to use location settings for the folders that hold static files:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="Content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Scripts">
      <system.web>
          <authorization>
              <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
      </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

P.S you will have to extract all public static content (public css files and scripts) to some other folder because Content and Scripts will require authentication.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, it is appreciated. However, in MVC, it is highly insecure and bad practice to use the authorizaiton element, and particularly location.  Additionally  the global filter wont ably the Authorize attribute on every request, only actions that go through the ASP.Net pipeline.  The idea, is that the forms authentication module gets triggered for any request, whether it goes through the asp.net pipeline or not, something that IIS 7+ supports (integrated vs classic of IIS6)

Comment: I didn't say that Authorize will be invoked on every request : "Autorize as global filter this way authentication and authorization will be required for all the actions in your application" - as you see here I am talking about controller actions which are executed by managed handler.

Comment: "in MVC, it is highly insecure and bad practice to use the authorizaiton element, and particularly location" - Can you provide some links about it ?

Comment: Without using locations the only way that you can run ALL the requests through managed pipline is by using <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> but this is not advised since there could be a serious performance panalty...

Comment: Hi Alex,
I've tried modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />  and that's accurate, there is a performance penalty.  Removing the managedHandler pre-condition from the module I'm interested in is equivalent for my use case, without the performance penalty, also not working.  With regards to the global filter, I'm aware that you mentioned "for all actions" but I have that there already, I need "for all requests", not only controller actions.

Comment: Here's a link with regards to it being insecure to use locations in MVC.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc