# Restrict direct access to All views show/Redirect to error page except Login page, if user enters direct URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4.

First page it is navigating to `http://localhost:61700/` where it has username and password to proceed further...

Now, I can also access direct url by typing `http://localhost:61700/AccountInfo` and other pages as well without login to the app.

How can I restrict this, if user not logged in and typed direct URL, it needs to go to the error page

**HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace myWebSite.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AccountStatus()
    {
      return View();
    }
...................
```

Comment: Apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to all your other controllers so the user is redirected to the login page.

Comment: Routing coolness, or all out forms authentication. Much can be found searching the web for forms based auth.

Comment: **@StephenMuecke**,  Actually it has to go to error page if I enter wrong URL

Comment: The authorize will play off of forms auth or other backing auth plans, am I correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock down paths in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @Erik Philips, that URL did not solved my problem... please read my question fully and remove your down vote :)

Comment: Then you didn't read it.  It's that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple idea:

1. Create a controller, say `SecureController` inherited from `Controller` and have only this method

   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {

   ```
       if (Session["LoggedIn"] == 1) {
           base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
       } else {
           filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
       }

   }
   ```
2. Other than the `LoginController`, inherit all other controllers from `SecureController`
3. Have Index (or name it whatever you like) method do the login.  Set `Session["LoggedIn"]` to 1 after successful login.

Thats all you need.  Of course this is just a simple thought provoking idea to put you on the right path.  This will allow you to redirect to any page if user is not logged in. No form authentication configuration required. This gives you total control on how to authenticate a user.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply Authorize attribute to make it restrict from unauthorized users. Also you can apply role and add user if  you want to.

```
[Authorize]

public class PrivateResourcesController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(DateTime.Now);
    }             
}


[Authorize(Roles ="Admin",Users ="foo@mail.com")]

public class PrivateResourcesController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(DateTime.Now);
    }             
}
```