# Restrict application to Active Directory group

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication

In ASP.NET MVC5 an Intranet application could be restricted to an Active Directory group using `web.config` like so:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="DOMAIN\group"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Where does this belong in an ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Comment: [Do not use the authorization attribute for asp.net-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11765196/209259).

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Core MVC application, you can use "Novell.LDAP" library. It has been ported to .NET Core you can find it in NuGet. There are lots of samples you can find.

And I assume you know policy authorization in .Net Core. You can authenticate users via Active Directory using Novell.LDAP and get their properties like group or anything else described in LDAP. So, when you sign in users, you can add claims to their identities and check them using "AuthorizeAttribute" as:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "DOMAIN\group")]
```

This attribute goes the policy you defined and checks it is authorized or not. I hope my answer helps.