# Setting up authorization and a "Access-denied" page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, authorization

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC application.  I want to deny access to all users who are unauthenticated or not in an AD group.  Only this AD group should have access.  The exception to this is the "You Shall Not Pass!" page.  Anyone can access that.

In the project root, I have this in my web.config (the rest of the file is trimmed for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On">
            <error statusCode="401" redirect="/ui/Other/YouShallNotPass.html" />
        </customErrors>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="allowedrole"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="401" />
            <error statusCode="401" 
                   subStatusCode="2" 
                   responseMode="ExecuteURL" 
                   path="/ui/Other/YouShallNotPass.html" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have a second web.config sitting next to `ui/Other/YouShallNotPass.html`.  I expect this to allow anyone to access this page, authenticated or otherwise:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I'm able to test this by setting the AD group to one that doesn't exist.  I'm not part of the non-existent group, so I should expect to see the `YouShallNotPass.html` page.

It's not working as expected.  I'm getting the following error in my browser:

> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.

If I request `YouShallNotPass.html` directly, I can access it after being prompted for a user/pass.

What am I doing incorrectly?  Why won't it serve the 401 page when the user isn't authorized?

Comment: Try inserting `<authentication mode="None" />` in the web.config of your `YouShallNotPass.html` and see what happens. Since the browser is still prompting a user/pass, it means the page is still requiring windows authentication (since your put it in the main web.config and didn't override it).

Comment: It no longer asks for a user/pass when I request `YouShallNotPass.html` directly.  But any other page and I still get the original error.

Comment: Is it possible that your access pool user doesn't have access to the database you are authenticating against?

Comment: Authentication works fine, and I'm not authenticating against a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc) because it explains why your solution won't work.

So once you move to annotate all your secure controller actions with [Authorize] you can add a custom ExceptionFilter

like this

```
public class HandleUnauthorizedAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() != typeof (SecurityException)) return;

        var controllerName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string) filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "Unauthorized",
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
}
```

Then wiring it up here

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleUnauthorizedAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this apply in my case?  `YouShallNotPass.html` is a static HTML file.  It isn't served by a controller.

Comment: The key piece is that you can't configure security in the web.config, where you lock down the whole site, then open up holes with the <location> like you did with asp.net webforms.  so 1.  use the authorize attribute on your controller actions 2. you might be able to use he customerrors after you do 1 because you aren't locking everything down.

Comment: one other issue is that your are mixing authentication (who you are) with authorization (what you can do) here.  an authentication error would be a 401.  an authorization error is a 403.

Comment: I'd also change to a view, like my solution because you can then see additional information on the error page like what they were trying to access.

Comment: I'm uninterested in changing it to a view.  1) I'm already using `[Authorize]`, 2) my custom errors section isn't working, 3) I'm locking everything down including static files, which can't be done using `Authorize`.

Comment: maybe try the old way and add a <location> tag in the web.config for your .html page
<location path="ThouShallNotPass.html">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/> // this will allow access to everyone to register.aspx

</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

Answer (score 1):

Managed to work around this by adding the following to my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Response.StatusCode != 401)
        return;

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.WriteFile("~/ui/Other/YouShallNotPass.html");
    Response.ContentType = "text/html";
}
```

I would have preferred using the web.config to do this, though.

Comment: Did you try using the `<location>` element in your main web.config instead of having a second web.config? That might be a cleaner alternative than having to intercept the response.

Comment: Yes I did.  I can't remember why it didn't work now, though.