# How to "lockdown" an MVC using authorization and authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I have been asked to create a poc using MVC that when a user goes to the site. It would restrict access to the entire website (authorization) out of the box. Then developers would begin to add Authorization attributes to unlock pages and features. Is this approach possible?

Currently in MVC, by default everything is "unlocked" to the end user once they have authenticated. Then a developer would add the authorize attributes to start locking down the site which is opposite approach i was tasked with.

Our use case for this approach is when a developer forgets to add the authorize attribute to a critical action. In this scenario, a sensitive feature is now unlocked to anyone authenticated to use the app. Note: The controller would not have an authorize attribute in this scenario.

EDIT: Added snippets

FilterConfig

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    }
}
```

Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize(Users = "Bob")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View(new LoginModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

After working on this for hours..i think i realized i was doing it correct. However, the reason why the 401 is not thrown without declaring the attributes is because the attribute is of course what fires off the code that throws the 401! LOL I have no idea how i missed this but hopefully nobody gets stuck in the loop i was today. Feel free to correct me if i am wrong though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock down paths in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765030/how-to-lock-down-paths-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I did read this article multiple times. I could be missing a detail but i have yet to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the AuthorizeAttribute globally using the FilterConfig then explicitly specify AllowAnonymousAttribute or specific roles using the AuthorizeAttribute on controllers or actions as you need them.

App_Start\FilterConfig.cs:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the current setup i am using but when i launch the website in Visual Studio, it does not throw a 401 for the login action results (default routing). However, when i hit login and it redirects me to the Index() it does throw a 401. What i am missing to make it always throw a 401? Basically only adding attributes to unlock things but init everything should throw 401.

Comment: If you have created a MVC app from the default VS template with some form of Authorization selected the Account controller will be created with the default AuthorizeAttribute on the controller but with the AllowAnonymousAttribute on the GET and POST Login actions. To prove the concept works simply create a new MVC application and run it to get the homepage. Then do as suggested above with the global filter and you will see you are pushed to the login page rather than the homepage. My guess is your issue is more likely to do with whether the request has actually been Authorised post login.

Comment: I'll give this a try. I have been creating the MVC app using the Windows Auth Template which doesn't create the account controller. I think i would have to choose the Individual Auth. I'll give it a try though!

Comment: You are correct, depending on the template i select, it will provide the "lock out" approach. However, is there a way to get Windows Auth template to provide the same result? I applied the same strategy above but it loads up the default routing page just fine. I'll keep tinkering with it.