# ASP.NET MVC5 CSS not applying to certain desktops

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I work at a hospital, and have developed a simple contact list application. I am using windows authentication. It works fine in most places, but on some desktops the style sheet does not load and it is a white screen with the raw data. I have went to the folder structure and made sure that IIS_IUSRS and IUSRS have permission to read it. And I have tried directly linking the web page to the CSS file. I have also added this code to my web.config file:

```
<location path="Content/Site">
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

None of these have made any difference to it. I can't figure out why it would work on some but not others.

I have impersonation set to true, and don't allow anonymous authentication.

Comment: In MVC, you don't need the location/authorization paths. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6571613/106866)

Comment: Browser + F12 (developer tools) is your friend.  You can watch the network traffic and see if the stylesheet is failing with 404, 401, etc and work from there.  Are you using bundles?

Comment: @paul I'm trying out the tool now, it' still trying to load the CSS. I am still pretty new to ASP.NET, so as far as bundles go I'm just using whatever is built in to visual studio. Looking at my _Layout file, I see it is using      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")