# MVC Customized Authentication filter not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, custom-authentication

I have 4 controllers namely `Account`, `Admin`, `Home` and `Gallery`. Out of this 4 controllers I only need to Authorize `Admin` controller and remaining can have access by anonymous. So I've decorated my home controller, gallery controller and account controller with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and I've my `Admin` controller decorated with my custom authorization filter named `[CustAuthFilter]` and it contains following code.

```
public class CustAuthFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
      var request = httpContext.Request;
      string controller = request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();
      if (controller != "" && controller == "admin")
      {
          var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
          if (!isAuthorized)
          {
                return false;
          }
          else
          {
                if (!object.ReferenceEquals(httpContext.Session["un"], null))
                {
                      return true;
                }
                else
                {
                      return false;
                }
           }
       }
       else
       {
          return true;
       }
     }

     override public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
     {
           base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
           if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
           {
               String url = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + "?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest";
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
           }
     }

     protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
     {
        String url = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
     }
}
```

and in my web.config I've following

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Admin/Index" timeout="2880" protection="Encryption" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

and I have registered my customized authorization attribute in filters as follows:

```
filters.Add(new CustAuthFilter());
```

But whenever I try to access `domainname/home` or `domainname/gallery` it will be automatically redirected to `domainname/account/login`. But I don't have any idea why even after decorating home and gallery controller with `[AllowAnonymous]` it is redirecting to Account controller!!

Comment: Is a breakpoint in the AuthorizeCore getting hit?

Comment: Yes @praveenpaulose.. but before it hits it will be routed to account controller.

Comment: If you just need to allow anonymous access to home, gallery why don't you remove the Authorize attribute from those controllers?

Comment: @praveenpaulose. I haven't added any authorize attribute to home, gallery or account controller and I have mentioned this in question clearly.

Comment: Sorry about that. Oversight.

Comment: Never mind @Praveenpaulose. Anyways am checking on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is happening because of the authorization config i.e.

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Remove this line from your config and it should be working after that.

You are trying to mix the authorization in Web.config and the Authorize attribute available in MVC. Read this link on a clear answer to not using the authorization tag [Authorize attribute vs authorization node in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571597/authorize-attribute-vs-authorization-node-in-web-config)

Comment: Perfect bro. Even I was thinking about the same but then I thought that if I include that in web config it will be relevant to only those controllers which has authorize or custom authentication attribute say in my case admin. Thanks for the link which explained most of them.. :)